# How do I list dates of latest posts for all feeds in Google Reader?

Tags: google-reader, rss

I have lots of feeds in Google Reader. Some of them are inactive for a long time. I'd like to clean it up.

What I'm looking for is a way to list all feeds with date of their latest post. That way I can see which ones are dead. Is it possible?

I think I saw this in Google Reader few years back, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your stuff | Trends](http://www.google.com/reader/view/?tab=cy#trends-page)

Then under "Subscription trends" click "inactive"

Comment: This is exactly it. I just couldn't locate it. Thank you!